# Delete duplicate from JOIN table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have query in PostgreSQL like this

```
SELECT 
c.id,
c.firstname,
c.lastname
FROM
tblperson c
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblorder p WHERE p.id = c.id)
ORDER BY
id,
firstname,
lastname
```

[as a result I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rthk3.png)

How can i delete second record as this POstgreSQL code

```
DELETE FROM
tblperson dup_lang
USING tblperson dist_lang
WHERE dup_lang.id < dist_lang.id
AND dup_lang.firstname= dist_lang.firstname
AND dup_lang.lastname= dist_lang.lastname;
```

Comment: 1) Change `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblorder p WHERE p.id = c.id)` to `...FROM tblperson c LEFT JOIN tblorder p ON c.id = p.id WHERE p.id IS NULL ...` 2) Why are you sure the second record is the one to delete? **ADD answer as update to question**.

Comment: Thanks Adrian Klaver, your suggestion is correct but I asked how to use query above and DELETE duplicated using query bellow . (DELETE FROM (SELECT 
c.id,
c.firstname,
c.lastname
FROM
tblperson c
WHERE
NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblorder p WHERE p.id = c.id)
ORDER BY
id,
firstname,
lastname) duplicate

Comment: 1) Add any new information to your question not in the comments. 2) The DELETE query in the comment does not match the DELETE query in the question. Which one is correct?  Again why is the second record the one being deleted?

Comment: I would like to use first query that gave me result of duplicate person and make DELETE duplicate person query using info from first query. Second DELETE query is example I found that could be used in combination with first query but I do not know how to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

A tentative answer based on the assumption that you want to delete both the records in `tblperson` that match the results of the query.

```
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM
   tblperson
WHERE
   id 
IN
(SELECT 
   c.id
FROM
   tblperson c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblorder p WHERE p.id = c.id)
ORDER BY
  id)
--Then either ROLLBACK; or COMMIT; depending on whether the query worked or not.
```

Comment: I got this SQL Error: ERROR:  update or delete on table "tblperson" violates foreign key constraint because there is related record in tblorder

Comment: You need to update your question with the complete table definitions for `tblperson` and `tblorder` including the Foreign Key relationships.